# Error while using categorical_crossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp

I am learning deep learning with tensorflow. I made a simple NLP code predicting the next word on a given sentence

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(num,64,input_length = max_len-1))   # we subtract 1 coz we cropped the laste word from X in out data
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model.add(Dense(num,activation = 'softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X,Y,epochs = 500)
```

however using categorical_crossentropy gives me the following error

````
ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (453, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes). If your targets are integer classes, you can convert them to the expected format via:
```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)
```

Alternatively, you can use the loss function `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead, which does expect integer targets.
````

Can someone explain me what does this mean and why i cant use categorical crossentropy loss function?
Thank you so much!
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Categorical cross entropy** is used for multi-class classification problems. When you use "softmax" as an activation, there will be **one node** for **each class** in the **output layer**. For each sample, the node corresponding to the class of the sample should be close to **one** and the remaining nodes should be close to **zero**. Thus, true class labels **Y** needs to be an **one-hot** encoding vector.

Suppose your class labels in Y are integers like 0,1,2,... Please try the code below.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(num,64,input_length = max_len-1))   # we subtract 1 coz we cropped the laste word from X in out data
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model.add(Dense(num,activation = 'softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])

Y_one_hot=to_categorical(Y) # convert Y into an one-hot vector
history = model.fit(X,Y_one_hot,epochs = 500)  # use Y_one_hot encoding instead of Y
```

Answer (score 1):

For the provided answer (by Roohollah Etemadi) you have to import the to_categorical as follows:

`from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical`